# How can I extract numeric ranges from 2 columns and print the range from both columns as tuples?

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy, awk

I'm quite new on bash scripting and on python programing; at the moment have 2 columns which contains numeric sequences as follow:

```
Col 1:
1
2
3
5
7
8

Col 2:

101
102
103
105
107
108
```

Need to extract the numeric ranges from both columns and print them according to the sequence break occrance on any of those 2 columns and the result should be as follow:

```
1,3,101,103

5,5,105,105

7,8,107,108
```

Already received a useful information on how to extract numeric ranges from one column using awk: - **$ awk 'NR==1||sqrt(($0-p)*($0-p))>1{print p; printf "%s", $0 ", "} {p=$0} END{print $0}' file** - ; but now the problem got a bit more complex as have to include a second column with another numeric sequence and requires as a result the ranges from the columns wherever the sequence breaks occurs on any of the 2 columns.

To add a bit more complexity the sequences can be ascending and/or descending.

Trying to find a solution using pandas (data frames) and numpy libraries for python.

Thanks in advances.

Hello MaxU thanks for your reply, unfortunately I'm hitting an issue for the following case:

Col 1:

```
 7
 8
 9
10
11


Col 2:

52
51
47
46
45
```

Where numeric sequence in the second column is descending from the begining; it generates as a result:

7,11,45,52

instead of:

7,8,51,52

8,11,45,47

Cheers.

Comment: why the R tag??

Comment: This is fairly doable with `rle` and `diff` in R.

Comment: I think that you are going to have to explain how that sequence works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [103]: df
Out[103]:
   Col1  Col2
0     7    52
1     8    51
2     9    47
3    10    46
4    11    45

In [104]: (df.groupby((df.diff().abs() != 1).any(1).cumsum()).agg(['min','max']))
Out[104]:
  Col1     Col2
   min max  min max
1    7   8   51  52
2    9  11   45  47
```

**OLD answer:**

Here is one way (among many) to do it in Pandas:

**Data:**

```
In [314]: df
Out[314]:
   Col1  Col2
0     1   101
1     2   102
2     3   103
3     5   105
4     8   108
5     7   107
6     6   106
7     9   109
```

NOTE: pay attention - rows with indexes (4,5,6) is a descending sequence

**Solution:**

```
In [350]: rslt = (df.groupby((df.diff().abs() != 1).all(1).cumsum())
     ...:           .agg(['min','max']))
     ...:

In [351]: rslt
Out[351]:
  Col1     Col2
   min max  min  max
1    1   3  101  103
2    5   5  105  105
3    6   8  106  108
4    9   9  109  109
```

now you can easily save it to CSV file:

```
rslt.to_csv(r'/path/to/file_name.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

or just print it:

```
In [333]: print(rslt.to_csv(index=False, header=None))
1,3,101,103
5,5,105,105
6,8,106,108
9,9,109,109
```

Comment: Hello @MaxU thanks for your reply unfortunately I'm hitting an issue for the following case:
           7        52
           8        51
           9        47
          10        46
          11        45
Where numeric sequence in the second column is descending from the begining; it generates as a result:
 7,11,45,52

Comment: @A.ALT, could you [post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40447158/edit) your data set in your question, as it's hardly readable in the comment?

Comment: it fits for what it is needed at the moment; clear, to the point and quick answers, Cheers AALT

Comment: Hello @MaxU, is there a way to run the same procedure but for cases where the sequences in one column increase/decreases by 1 and in the second columns increase/decreses by 2?; cheers - This case just came up, found in the pandas documentations that it is possible to do it using the groupped option, but haven't been able to sort it out.

Comment: @A.ALT, could you please open a new question with a small sample data set and desired (expected) data set?

Comment: done, it has been posted : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607709/how-to-extract-numeric-ranges-from-2-columns-containig-numeric-sequences-and-pri