# How to extract numeric ranges from 2 columns based on mathematical operations used as criterias for each column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Working with PANDAS data frames for python and based on a previous question ([How to extract numeric ranges from 2 columns containig numeric sequences and print the range from both columns (different increment values)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607709/how-to-extract-numeric-ranges-from-2-columns-containig-numeric-sequences-and-pri)); got the following question: Is there a way of using pandas data frame to create numeric ranges based on different mathematical operations for each column?

e.g:

```
col1    col2   criteria-col1 diff. >2     criteria-col2 diff<=3                
1       23    abs(2-1)=1 ; no break     abs(27-23)=4;no break          
2       27    abs(4-2)=2 ; no break     abs(31-27)=4;no break
4       31    abs(6-4)=2;  no break     abs(35-31)=4;no break
6       35    abs(9-6)=3; break            abs(40-35)=5; no break but still break due to col1 criteria
9       40    abs(11-9)=2; no break    abs(45-40)=5;no break
11      45    abs(13-11)=2;no break    abs(49-45)=4;no break
13      49    abs (51-49)=2;no break   abs (51-49)=2; break also in column 1 due to critera in col2
15      51
```

Criteria : Create numeric ranges where the sequence (ascending or descending) is trucanted by any value >2

Criteria: create numeric ranges where the numeric sequence (ascending or descending) is trucanted by any value <=3

The expected result should be the ranges where the sequences break according to the criterias shown above:

```
col1_from  col1_to   col2_from  col2_to
        1        6          23       35
        9       13          40       49
       15       15          51       51
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear... Do you have a DF with __two__ columns or are your building the second column? Can you show your input data set and a desired one?

Comment: My mistake, and yes have a DF with 2 columns and the aim is to get ranges based on the criterias, any difference >2 for the 1st column and <=3 for the second column; whenever the criteria occurs on it specific column then a new segment should be created no matter if the other column still keeps it sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Data:**

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
   col1  col2
0     1    23
1     2    27
2     4    31
3     6    35
4     9    40
5    11    45
6    13    49
7    15    51
```

**Solution:**

```
In [11]: df.groupby(df.diff().abs().eval("col1 > 2 or col2 <= 3").cumsum()) \
           .agg(['min','max'])
Out[11]:
  col1     col2
   min max  min max
0    1   6   23  35
1    9  13   40  49
2   15  15   51  51
```

**Explanation:**

```
In [12]: df.diff()
Out[12]:
   col1  col2
0   NaN   NaN
1   1.0   4.0
2   2.0   4.0
3   2.0   4.0
4   3.0   5.0
5   2.0   5.0
6   2.0   4.0
7   2.0   2.0

In [13]: df.diff().abs().eval("col1 > 2 or col2 <= 3")
Out[13]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
dtype: bool

In [14]: df.diff().abs().eval("col1 > 2 or col2 <= 3").cumsum()
Out[14]:
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    2
dtype: int32
```